# Pipe output from mongosh MongoDB Shell to output file (Windows)

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

I am using the current `mongosh` tool to run Mongo queries which may return very large result sets, which might not fit within the buffer of the command prompt (and even if they did, copying such results by hand would be time consuming and error prone).  Therefore, I would like to have the ability to:

- pipe the output from `mongosh` to a text file, and
- also pass in a Mongo script or query to run from the command line

Here is the command I am currently running (details masked):

```
mongosh "mongodb://10.20.30.40:26017" --username my_username --password my_password
    --authenticationDatabase my_database > output.txt
```

This is the current output I see in `output.txt`:

```
Current sessionID:  1ee96e0f6025ec328ea25ccc
Connecting to:      mongodb://10.20.30.40:26017
Using MongoDB:      3.4.13
Using Mongosh Beta: 0.0.6

For more information about mongosh, please see our docs: https://docs.mongodb.com/mongodb-shell/

[1G[0J> [3G
```

So it seems that redirection to the output file is working.  However, I can't seem to figure out how to specify a Mongo script with an actual query to the command line tool.  For example, if I wanted to specify the following simple count query, how would I do it?

```
db.getCollection('my_collection').count();
```

Ideally, I would like `output.txt` to just have a single line with the count from this collection.

The earlier `mongo` command line tool seemed to have a number of ways of piping in a query, e.g. by specifying a script or using the `--eval` option.  The [documentation for mongosh](https://docs.mongodb.com/mongodb-shell/) claims that this tool is in Beta mode and supports some subset of `mongo` functionality.  Does it support the ability to pass a query?

Answer (score 1):

Meanwhile this also works with new `mongosh`, ensure you downloaded the latest version (1.1.9 or newer)

```
echo "db.getCollection('my_collection').countDocuments({});" | mongosh --norc --quiet > output.txt

mongosh --norc --quiet > output.txt <<EOF
db.getCollection('my_collection').countDocuments({});
EOF

mongosh --norc --quiet --eval "db.getCollection('my_collection').countDocuments({})" > output.txt
```

Note, with classic `mongo` shell you get this warning:

```
================
Warning: the "mongo" shell has been superseded by "mongosh",
which delivers improved usability and compatibility.The "mongo" shell has been deprecated and will be removed in
an upcoming release.
We recommend you begin using "mongosh".
For installation instructions, see
https://docs.mongodb.com/mongodb-shell/install/
================
```

which is not true in my opinion, I don't see new `mongosh` as successor for `mongosh`, yet. But I have to admit, it is getting better and better.

The only way to get rid of this warning is the `--eval` option.

Comment: Thanks but did you actually try this?  The other answer did not try it.

Comment: I use these with classic mongo shell. As mentioned mongosh is still too new for me.

Answer (score 0):

The following works in mongo (I am yet to try it with mongosh)

```
mongo --eval "db=db.getSiblingDB('DB NAME'); printjson(db.COLLECTION.findOne())" > output.txt --quiet
```

So yours would become:

```
mongo "mongodb://10.20.30.40:26017" --username my_username --password my_password --authenticationDatabase my_database --eval "db=db.getSiblingDB('my_database'); printjson(db.my_collection.count())" > output.txt --quiet
```

Comment: `I am yet to try it with mongosh` ... I need a solution for `mongosh`.

Comment: Only "data" apparent in the `output.txt` file is `[1G[0J> [3G` ... maybe this is some weird encoding, or maybe gibberish, but your second option is not working for me.

Comment: Correct, it might have changed in the new version. Documentation says, you can do --eval, while help says otherwise.

Comment: From help page mongosh does not support option `--eval` as of my version 0.5.2. However in current doc [mongosh Options](https://docs.mongodb.com/mongodb-shell/reference/options) it seems to be available.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen this is a bug, which is reported to MongoDB now.

Comment: You can try: `mongosh --eval "..." --norc --quiet` and that should work too

Answer (score 0):

As mentionned in the mongoDB Documentation, You can write your js script and use it with the --file option in the commandline.

```
mongosh --norc --quiet --file "test_script.js" > output.txt
```

to write the output of queries like :
`db.<collection_name>.findOne();`

Use this syntax in your jscript:
`printjson ( db.<collection_name>.findOne() );`

more details:
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/mongodb-shell/write-scripts/

Answer (score 0):

My colleague Cedric provided this solution which worked to capture the output completely

Of note are

- The "your_execution_db" besides the user name.
- More importantly, your .js script SHOULD NOT have a USE statement inside it!  If it has a USE statement, the output gets suppressed!

This format captures the output inside the .js script such as:

- print ("hello world");
- printjson({"UserId":101,"UserName":"John","UserCoreSuject":["Java","MongoDB","MySQL","SQL Server"]});
- console.log('Getting jobs collection...');
  console.log(db.getCollection('jobs'));

Syntax:

```
mongosh.exe --norc --host=ReplicaSetHostName1.comp.com:27000,ReplicaSetHostName2.comp.com:27000,ReplicaSetHostName3.comp.com:27000 --username=your_user your_execution_db --password MySuperSecurePassword --authenticationDatabase=admin_or_your_auth_db --file "C:\Temp\MyScript.js" -quiet > C:\Temp\MyScript.js.log
```